# How to run Google Colab file locally and save Runtime forever

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I have a large project I am working on in Google Colab, and every time I close my browser I lose my runtime, which is annoying because I have to run everything again.

Is there any way that I can run my colab .ipynb file locally so that my runtime is saved and I don't  have to re run every cell?

Comment: I don't know, what you understand by running colab file locally, did you mean running .ipynb file locally?

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to run the .ipynb file locally and not lose my runtime. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I also have the same problem, I tried looking online but I couldn't really find any solutions

Comment: Please accept the answer if satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Running .ipynb files locally is easy. My way to do it:

Using VSCode, you download Jupyter notebook extensions:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter

Open your .ipynb file and voila, your runtime is saved as long as your computer is running. If you want to save runtime even when shutting computer, you can use VSCode on VirtualBox with Linux or Windows. After you finish, just click "Save machine state" after clicking Exit button and then restore session when you return to your work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Colab allows you to do exactly that, use Colab as front-end and your own hardware as back-end.

Instructions here
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Which you reach when clicking > "Connect to a local runtime"

[image]